# GROUP BY rows in DataFrame/table in Pandas/iPython notebook (Jupyter)?

Tags: sqlite, pandas, apache-spark-sql, pandas-groupby, pandasql

I have a table which looks like this:

Current DataFrame/Table: 'original_table'

```
   col_1          col_2             col_3
0  Non-Saved      www.google.com    10
1  Non-Saved      www.facebook.com  20
2  Non-Saved      www.linkedin.com  20
3  Saved          www.Quora.com     30
4  Saved          www.gmail.com     40
```

Can I derive a table such as the following using SQL query?

```
    col_1          col_2             col_3
 0  Non-Saved      www.google.com    50
                   www.facebook.com
                   www.linkedin.com
 1  Saved          www.Quora.com     70
                   www.gmail.com
```

Basically I am expecting a table to have DISTINCT values from col_1, all corresponding values from col_2 and SUM(col_3) for corresponding values from col_3 in one row.

My query:

```
 sql("""SELECT col_1, group_concat(col_2) as col_2, SUM(col_3) as col_3
 FROM original_table
 GROUP BY col_1
 """).show()
```

I tried by using an embedded SQL query using [group_concat](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) but it gives me the following error:

```
AnalysisException: u"Undefined function: 'GROUP_CONCAT'. This function 
is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function 
registered in the database 'default'.
```

Can anyone please help me with probably a simple hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) - it return same size `Series` as original group:

```
#first convert column to numeric
df['col_3'] = df['col_3'].astype(int) #float

df['col_3'] = df.groupby('col_1')['col_3'].transform('sum')
print (df)
       col_1             col_2  col_3
0  Non-Saved    www.google.com     50
1  Non-Saved  www.facebook.com     50
2  Non-Saved  www.linkedin.com     50
3      Saved     www.Quora.com     70
4      Saved     www.gmail.com     70
```

And if need only first value:

```
df[['col_1','col_3']] = df[['col_1','col_3']].mask(df['col_1'].duplicated())
print (df)
       col_1             col_2  col_3
0  Non-Saved    www.google.com   50.0
1        NaN  www.facebook.com    NaN
2        NaN  www.linkedin.com    NaN
3      Saved     www.Quora.com   70.0
4        NaN     www.gmail.com    NaN
```

If necessary, `NaN`s is possible replace by empty string - in first `string` column no problem, but in last get mixed types - strings with numbers and some function should failed:

```
df[['col_1','col_3']] = df[['col_1','col_3']].mask(df['col_1'].duplicated()).fillna('')
print (df)
       col_1             col_2 col_3
0  Non-Saved    www.google.com    50
1             www.facebook.com      
2             www.linkedin.com      
3      Saved     www.Quora.com    70
4                www.gmail.com
```

---

```
print (df['col_3'].apply(type))
0    <class 'float'>
1      <class 'str'>
2      <class 'str'>
3    <class 'float'>
4      <class 'str'>
Name: col_3, dtype: object
```

Comment: `df['col_3'] = df.groupby('col_1')['col_3'].transform('sum')`

gave me:

               `col_1 col_2 col_3
        Non-Saved www.google.com 102020
        Non-Saved www.facebook.com 102020
        Non-Saved www.linkedin.com 102020
        Saved         www.Quora.com 3040
        Saved         www.gmail.com 3040`

Comment: You need first convert column 3 to number like `df['col_3'] = df['col_3'].astype(int)`

Comment: That works now. Is it possible to get the result in 2 rows in this case?
Thanks!

Comment: If want `DataFrame` as output then no, it is not possible - all columns have to be filled - so if no value then NaNs.

Comment: Cool Thanks! I'll try to do it by an user-defined function. I'll accept this answer so the question is not left unanswered.